# SQL performance worsens on adding an INNER JOIN clause in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have the following query

```
SELECT pri.*
  FROM patientreceiptitem pri 
  JOIN patientfinancialtransaction_patientreceiptitem pp ON pri.id = pp.receiptitems_id
  JOIN patientfinancialtransaction pft ON pp.patientfinancialtransaction_id = pft.id 
 WHERE pri.createtime >= '2020-03-01'
   AND pri.createtime < '2020-04-01'
```

It runs in 1.79 seconds and gives an output of 111, 793 rows

However, when I add a condition that is more restrictive as follows:

```
 JOIN patientbillconcession pbc ON pbc.id = pft.concession_id
```

the performance degrades dramatically. It now takes 8.185 seconds for an output of 10,338 rows. The same degradation is seen if I add a condition to the JOIN clause for the `pft` table:

```
SELECT pri.*
  FROM patientreceiptitem pri 
  JOIN patientfinancialtransaction_patientreceiptitem pp ON pri.id = pp.receiptitems_id
  JOIN patientfinancialtransaction pft ON pp.patientfinancialtransaction_id = pft.id 
       AND pft.concession_id IS NOT NULL
 WHERE pri.createtime >= '2020-03-01'
   AND pri.createtime < '2020-04-01'
```

`concession_id` is indexed in the `pft` table.

Any pointers would be great.

I'm running Postgres 12 on Arch Linux. My client is DBeaver 7.3.2.

Update 1:
I found that changing the following to a LEFT JOIN completes the query in 1.914 seconds:
`LEFT JOIN patientbillconcession pbc ON pbc.id = pft.concession_id`

But adding `AND pft.concession_id IS NOT NULL` to the WHERE clause once again degrades the performance to 7.938 seconds

Comment: Since this is a programming question that isn't specific to Ubuntu, you should post your question to [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).  You will get more help, as well.

Comment: "I'm running Postgres 12 on Arch Linux." This site does not support arch; only official Ubuntu.

Comment: @Ray - Thanks. I had Stackoverflow in mind and posted it here by mistake. Sorry.

Comment: @Rinzwind - Sorry. How do I remove or cancel this question now? I've posted it on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Having `pft.concession_id IS NOT NULL` in the query is irrelevant as `NULL` values cannot be joined. They will be excluded naturally because `JOIN patientbillconcession` demands that a matching `patientfinancialtransation` record exist.

The simplest way forward would be to [start with `EXPLAIN`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-explain/). PostgreSQL can then tell you why it's taking so long to return results:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT pri.* FROM patientreceiptitem pri ...
```

Comment: Thanks. I meant to say that the performance degrades if I add `pft.concession_id IS NOT NULL` without the JOIN clause for patientbillconcession